# How to merge two js to one properly to avoid conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onload, document-ready

I would like to merge two js to avoid conflicts which are happening right now, but I dont know JS good enough. I have element, that hides on click and i need it hidden on load. Right now it is visible on load. So I tried to make click on load, but it is causing issues. So how should I merge these two js to one?

```
        <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".infox").click();
                    });
        </script>

        <script>
                      $(document).on("click", ".infox", function() {
                         $(".infoBlock").toggleClass("in out");
                         $(".minus7").slideToggle();
                         $(".crosx").toggleClass("rotex");
                      });
        </script>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You could just export the toggle code in an own function, and call this function on click and on load, e.g. `var toggle = function () { $(".infoBlock").toggleClass("in out"); $(".minus7").slideToggle(); $(".crosx").toggleClass("rotex"); }` and than just call `$(document).ready(toggle);` and `$(document).on("click", ".infox", toggle);`

Comment: You could set the initial state if the elements via CSS so they are loaded that ways. Then just change the appearance via a click handler

Comment: – steeno It worked! Thanks very much! This should be the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add code in single script tag that will merge the code ---

```
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
                        $(".infox").click();
                        });
     $(document).on("click", ".infox", function() {
                             $(".infoBlock").toggleClass("in out");
                             $(".minus7").slideToggle();
                             $(".crosx").toggleClass("rotex");
                          });
  </script>
```